# Import a variable in a function in a class in one module to another

Tags: python, tornado

I want help on how I would get a variable in a class function sent to another module in python. For example:

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render('main.html')

    def post(self):
        event = self.get_argument('event')
        print event
        return event
```

How can I use the event variable in another python module?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make it `self.event` ...

the reason for this is that event only exists in the scope of post method as it is...
it is created when you call post and destroyed when you exit post

this page may help explain scope and variable lifetimes for you

http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/python-variable-scope-notes/

Module 1

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    event = None
    def get(self):
        self.render('main.html')

    def post(self):
        MainHandler.event = self.get_argument('event')
        print event
        return event
```

Module 2

```
from module1 import MainHandler
print MainHandler.event
```

Comment: Thanks, so would I declare event as a global variable? Then when it's initialized within the function it can be used outside of the function or module?

Comment: How do I attach it to the class?